# Java.Lang.String in Integer cannot be applied to (android.Text.Editable) android studio

Tags: android

Try to take an integer and convert to EditText.

```
@BindView(R.id.goodQuantity)
EditText goodQuantity; 

controller.save(new Item(Integer.parseInt(goodQuantity.getText())));
```

The error says

```
parse(int) Java.Lang.String in Integer cannot be applied to (android.text.Editable)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the text in `String` form, from `EditText` and than convert to `Int`:

```
controller.save(new Item(Integer.parseInt(goodQuantity.getText().toString())));
```

Answer (score 3):

[getText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) returns an `Editable` so you need to apply `toString()` to convert it into `String`

Put your code in `try-catch` because if there is no number or even the input is empty the it will cause a crash

```
    try{
       controller.save(new Item(Integer.parseInt(goodQuantity.getText().toString())));
                                     //                                   ^^^^ 
    }catch(Exception e){
      // Invalid input 
    }
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
controller.save(new Item(Integer.parseInt(goodQuantity.getText().toString())));
```

**.toString()**  is Required